# What is the MXML syntax to assign properties of subcomponents in custom MXML Components?

Tags: apache-flex, syntax, mxml

I am working on a custom Flex 4 component which is an aggregation of two existing flex components.  I would like to be able to specify my own custom properties for the component as well as access the existing public subcomponent properties via MXML.  For instance I might want to adjust the font color or style for the label and text input.

A toy component which aggregates both a label and a text input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
     >  
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable] public var prompt:String = "default prompt";
        [Bindable] public var input:String = "default inpput";
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup>
    <s:Label id="cLabel" text="{prompt}" />
    <s:TextInput id="cTextInput" text="{input}" />
</s:VGroup>
</s:Group>
```

Then in my main application I would like to access the public interfaces of the sub-component via mxml without re-writing a pass-through binding for every one.  Something like:

```
...
<local:myInput prompt="name" input="please enter name">
    <local:cLabel color="0xffffff" />
    <local:CTextInput fontStyle="bold" />
</local:myInput>
```

In actionscript one can do this easily for all public properties:

```
myInput.cLabel.color = "0xffffff";
```

But I am stumped on the syntax for MXML.  This seems like it should be easy, but I have not found the answer yet.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't daisy chain down an display hierarchy w/ the MXML tag/value.  You can do it in ActionScript, as you specified, but even that would probably be considered a bad practice.

I'll point out that [color](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html#styleSummary) on the Label and [fontStyle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html#styleSummary) on the TextInput are not properties.  They are styles  So, the code you have:

```
myInput.cLabel.color = "0xffffff";
```

Would most likely throw an error because color is not a property.  You'd have to use code like this:

```
myInput.cLabel.setStyle('color',"0xffffff");
```

However, since styles are usually inherited by the children; I suspect at the top level component, you can set the style and it would immediately trickle through to the children automatically.  So, you should just be able to do:

```
myInput.setStyle('color',"0xffffff");
```

Or in MXML:

```
<local:myInput prompt="name" input="please enter name" color="0xffffff" fontStyle="bold"  >
</local:myInput>
```

And it should trickle on down.  Things can get trickier if you want to set styles individually on child components.

But, back to your original question w/ regards to properties.  To keep a component encapsulated, you should create properties that set on the children. Something like this:

```
private var _property : String;
public function get property():String{
 return _property;
}
public function set property(value:String){
 _property = value;
 myChildComp.property = value;
}
```

It can suck if you need to do this for a lot of properties.  If encapsulation of this component isn't a priority; just set them in ActionScript.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on the style values, I should have used a better example which depended on properties.  IMO writing getters and setters for every interface of an aggregate class leads to tighter coupling than if one could just compose orthogonal classes together.  I guess I just need to get used to writing a lot of boiler plate if I want to compose components together.  Would another option be to create an MXML template class and have the entire components passed in as arguments?  Something like the Flex Form class?